# Properly expanding an element with a scroll bar to fit child content width

Tags: html, css

Say I have a `<ul>` with the following css:

```
position:relative;
border: solid;
border-radius:2px;
height:350px;
overflow:auto;
padding-left: 2px;
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
```

When I add `<li>` elements to the `<ul>` as its children, the div expands horizontally in order to fit the width of the child nodes.

However, the scroll bar takes up space within the div.

When enough children are added to require the scroll bar, the widest text nodes wrap the last word.

The only way I have found to fix this behavior is to set the `<ul>`s `white-space` property to `nowrap`, but that just makes the text flow past the boundary, rather than expanding the boundary itself and creates an ugly horizontal scroll bar.

### Demo

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*Uncomment below to see the effect of adding nowrap*/
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>LONG STUFF-STUFF</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>short</li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle  of the same snippet, in case you prefer to work with that: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0s231g/1/

Comment: Add working code snippet, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<ul>` element is already shrinking to fit, as it's set to `inline-block`. You just have to add extra room for the scrollbar.

Add:

```
overflow-x: clip;
padding-right: 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tjjmuf0/)

Comment: Which browsers support `overflow-x: clip`? http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-clip, it's only in editors’ draft.

Comment: It's true, it doesn't seem to be officially supported much, but it acts very similar to `overflow-x: hidden`, which can also be used here